# Transaction confirmed, bitcoin not received

Tags: transactions

Is that normal to receive more than 6 confirmation in the Bitcoin transaction process? Because the time delay is unbelievable and I received 64 already. But according to blockchain.info, 6 confirmation enough for Bitcoin transaction.

So my question is, how much exactly transactions I have to receive at the end to be sure it's confirmed?
Because I sent my Bitcoin in the morning and now the night, but it still did not reach its destination and keep sending confirmations.

https://blockchain.info/tx/0e1ed99dc9932ec6725f9e3f0f406ac7305d53e9752f1b56a61dd8259d53f1b4

[image]

Comment: I've already sent the request to support stuff, but no response at the moment(probably needs some time) The question is, can I cancel the transaction and repay or resend necessary amount BTC again?

Comment: Why do you say it did not reach its destination? The image you pasted confirms that it reached its destination.

Comment: Closely related: [Recipient has “not received” the Bitcoin I sent, but the transaction is confirmed](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/92058/5406)

Answer (score 1):

Your transaction is confirmed. As Rutger said 1 confirmation is enough, more just means more confidence. You should double-check the addresses you used, it's possible the coins were sent to the wrong place.

Comment: It's the second day already, but my payment didn't show up, what do I do in that case? Because I checked on the blockchain.info and it looks perfectly fine. Probably there is a place where I might check again?

Comment: Where did you get the destination address from? Go back to where you got the address from and find it again, and make sure it is the same as the one in your wallet from your screenshot. Also what is the destination? How do you know it didn't arrive?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is completely normal.

It simply means that there are more blocks being build ontop of the block your transaction was put in / originated from.

The more confirmations = less chance of your transaction being reverted in a 51% attack.

> > So my question is, how much exactly transactions I have to receive at the end to be sure it's confirmed? Because I sent my Bitcoin in the morning and now the night, but it still did not reach its destination and keep sending confirmations.

Usually 1 confirmation would be enough, ( to prevent double-spending, which to this day does still happen quite a bit.)

Theorethically 6 would be the most optimal. ( Unless there is a 51% attack.)

> With six confirmations it is essentially mathematically impossible for an attacker with less than 51% of all mining capacity to get six blocks in a row. and still surpass the longest block chain. With 51% or a lot more than 51% the attacker can get six confirmations by creating a parallel blockchain in which only transactions approved by the attacker get included in blocks.

Comment: And how long do you think it will take to confirm transaction in my case? It's not an emergency, just to be prepared.

Comment: Anything over 1 confirmation with the current state of the network should be seen as confirmed.